# trying to webscrape poocoin.app with jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

im currently making a discord bot that checks shitcoin prices. when trying to use Jsoup to scrape the page im getting the cloudflare ddos-protection message instead of showing me the content of the site. Can i fix this?

```
public class Scraping {
public static void main(String[] args) {
final String url = "https://poocoin.app/tokens/0x5232152c8207653aeda5baa0ff7fb1046c23c753";
   try { 
       final Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("mozilla").ignoreHttpErrors(true).get();
       String page = document.text();
       System.out.println(page);
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

}

```
Just a moment... Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page. Checking your browser before accessing poocoin.app. Please enable Cookies and reload the page. This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly. Please allow up to 5 seconds… Redirecting… DDoS protection by Cloudflare Ray ID: 6507827f2bb500df
```